# how to get an array from a php explode result?

Tags: php, json

```
$_SESSION['consequnce1']=[1,2,3]
$consequenceStr1=implode( ',', $_SESSION['consequence1']); //for storage to databases
$_SESSION['consequence1']=explode(',', $consequence1);
```

//$_SESSION['consequence1'] now is like["1","2","3"].

in html, I want get the array[1,2,3].

```
var sess = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['consequence1']); ?>");

         var num =sess[0];
```

but this two line code does not work, what's the problem?
thanks

Answer: do not know the reason in fact. But just change

```
var sess = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['consequence1']); ?>;
```

then it works.
Thanks for others' reply

Comment: Whats the output then? Note the missing `e` and  `1`.

Comment: the spelling of `consequence` in jquery seems to be wrong

Comment: `$_SESSION['consequence1']=array_map('intval', explode(',', $consequence1));`

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER thanks, but just an example, I revised the question anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is, because `json_encode` provides value that can be used directly in JavaScript. It wraps strings in double quotes and takes care of other types to be valid as well. `JSON.parse` takes string as an argument, which is not necessary.

In your example, you had messed double quotes, like this:

```
JSON.parse("["1","2","3"]")
```